# Print the entire list of values

Tags: c++

I am new in C++. I've been trying to create an array which will let you insert values and show that values.
So far I create an array that allows me to insert value and shows the grade (highest and lowest).

How can I print the entire list of grades?

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    int grade;
    int num;
    int lowest=999;
    int highest=0;

    cout<< "\n number of grade?";
    cin>> num;
    for(int i=1; i<=num;i++)
    {
        cout<< "\n the grade "<<i<< "?";
        cin>> grade[i];

        if (grade [i] > highest) highest = grade[i];
        cout<<" highest grade " << highest;
        if (grade [i] < lowest) lowest = grade[i];
        cout<<" lowest grade " <<lowest;

    }
    cout<<"\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where's the array? and `int grade;  cin>> grade[i];` ?

Comment: I see you are aware of for loop, printing via `std::cout` and accessing the element at index i. How can't you figure it out?

Comment: @Arun A.S It's probably at global scope, with missing includes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you want to print out the grades, then

```
for(int i=1; i<=num;i++)
{
    cout << grade[i] << endl ;
}
```

But please do know that arrays are indexed from 0 to size - 1.

Comment: do you know how can i sort the list from lowest to highest

Comment: Do note, in the question we have `int grade;` means that `grade` **isn't an array**.

Comment: @NikBougalis , yes, that is true. But later in the OP's code, he does `cin>> grade[i];` , so I believe the OP meant `grade` to be an array but had a typo.